# How to create two packages on github in the same project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with maven in java that I generate a package on github, but I need to generate a package for the develop branch and another for the master branch, both must be active and must be accessible?

Knowing how to generate two packages in the master and develop branches

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.